# Convert a XML Schema (XSD) document to a tree like structure

Tags: xml, schema, tree

I am in real trouble. I want to convert an XML schema (XSD) document into a tree like structure. Is there any straight way of doing it?

I used XMLBeans to parse the XSD document and tried to traverse the parsed document. But, handling the gory details of XSD was not easy. Thereby, I left that and searching for a much cleaner way.

Please help.

Thanks,
Aatish

Comment: XSD's are XML, so they can be loaded into any DOM tree that supports XML parsing (pretty much all of them).  It would helpful to know more specifically what you are trying to solve - is the problem just that XMLBeans require you to write more boilerplate code than you desire?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "tree-like structure"? XML is already hierarchal, which by most definitions is tree-like. Are you talking about a visualization?

Comment: Yes. I am talking about visualization. Just like Tree structure of Swing where u can expand and collapse.

Comment: But, xsd schemas can be written in many ways like: I can define the element somewhere in the XSD and then just refer it using ref="" OR I can use name="" and this implicitly means that it is defined somewhere else. So, it becomes a bit tricky to traverse and place the right children under every parent. Also, I just know of these two techniques (i.e. using ref="" and name=""; maybe there are more than this. So, I am not able to write a fully functional conversion from XSD to JTree like representation of Swing.

Comment: Also, there can be same attribute names but in other elements. I was not able to handle all these. I had used a DOM Parser and its API to parse the XSD file and access children nodes, element, attributes, and other types.

Answer (score 0):

try XSDViewer.sh or XSDViewer.bat from http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/

it shows the xsd in swing tree.